# How to remove and add tabs under product information in the admin panel?

Tags: magento, tabs, admin, edit, product

I have a custom tab under the product edit page in the admin panel where i can upload my images. The tab is showing up with the following code:

```
<adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
    <reference name="product_tabs">
        <action method="addTab">
            <name>my_custom_tab</name>
            <block>imageupload/adminhtml_catalog_product_tab</block>
        </action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
```

The Custom Tab is now visible for existing products. Now I also need to display the tab if I create a new product, so this is what i've tried:

```
<adminhtml_catalog_product_new>
        <reference name="product_tabs">
            <action method="addTab">
                <name>new_svg_upload</name>
                <block>imageupload/adminhtml_catalog_product_tab</block>
            </action>
        </reference>
</adminhtml_catalog_product_new>
```

The problem is, the tab is also visible in the page where you can select what type of product the new product should be (simple, grouped etc).

[image: Product Settings]

So how can I make this tab only visible at the product page. The second question is how can i disable the standard "image" tab from Magento via xml.

Any help would be great. Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thnx for your question.
Writing your tab class `imageupload/adminhtml_catalog_product_tab` make it implement 
`Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface`.
One of the methods you will have to implement is `canShowTab`.
So just add logic that  is used for rendering `_new` page:

```
    $product = $this->getProduct();

    if (!($setId = $product->getAttributeSetId())) {
        $setId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('set', null);
    }
    if ($setId) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
```

Now you tab is displayed only for products with type_id.